# Generic Static Class in C# - All Types Instantiated?

Tags: c#, .net, generics

Probably one for the language experts here, but if I create a static generic class that looks as follows:

```
public static class MyClass<T>{
   private static Dictionary<T,string> _someStorage = new Dictionary<T,string>();
}
```

When my program starts, will all possible types have their own dedicated instance of `MyClass` in memory, or is this created at run-time, or through some compiler magic?

As I understand, a non-generic static class is always 'present' in memory (unless I am wrong about this...)

Comment: There will be one instance per type, `T`. However, the instances are only created *as they are needed*. This applies to non generic static types too.

Comment: I think the static constructor only runs when a static instance is accessed so it would suggest they don't exist at the start of the app, only when the framework requires them. Yes there will be a separate static per generic type